# won't multiple tags sometimes reduce the chance of an answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

Background: I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140335/how-to-integrate-bottle-into-a-script) about starting two "actions" and both of them are supposed to run in a loop. I was wondering how to avoid using a process and gave an example of code.

When choosing the tags, `python` was obvious but then I started to wonder if adding `tkinter` and `bottle` is a good idea:

- on the one hand they describe my exact problem, so people who use either or both of these modules may have thought about it before, and `users_of(bottle) < users_of(python)` (same for `tkinter`)
- on the other hand there will be people who will see `python` (*good, I know that*), then bottle (*ah, no idea, skipping*). They may have had the answer to the general question, though (*how to start two actions ...*)

Should tags be seen as connected with an `AND` or and `OR`?

Comment: I know that when I filter for tags, I see the result of an OR operation. At that point I personally look at the title to decide whether I think I can answer. I don't know about everyone else.